# How to keep duplicated rows that repeat exactly n times in pandas DataFame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have DataFrame that looks like this, with ~10k rows:

```
    peak start  peak end    motif_start   motif_end    strand   
0   948         177         3210085       3210103      -        
1   948         177         3210047       3210065      +        
2   062         419         3223269       3223287      -        
3   062         419         3223229       3223247      +        
4   062         419         3223232       3223250      +
.
.
.
```

Some of the rows repeat from 2 to 8 times in the 'peak start' column. I need to cut out to a new DataFrame rows that repeat exactly n times (n between 2 to 8).

Desired output:

```
n=2
    peak start  peak end    motif_start   motif_end    strand   
0   948         177         3210085       3210103      -        
1   948         177         3210047       3210065      +
```

```
n=3
    peak start  peak end    motif_start   motif_end    strand
2   062         419         3223269       3223287      -        
3   062         419         3223229       3223247      +        
4   062         419         3223232       3223250      +
```

And so on for each n.

I tried:

```
new_df = df.groupby('peak start').head(n)
```

but it also returns first n rows, for rows that repeat more than n times.

I am new to Python, so looking for maybe existing method that I am not aware of, rather then iterating over the data frame and counting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.transform` and `count` with a boolean filter.

```
s = df.groupby('peak_start')['peak_start'].transform('count')
```

---

```
df[s == 2]
   peak_start  peak_end  motif_start  motif_end strand
0         948       177      3210085    3210103      -
1         948       177      3210047    3210065      +


print(df[s == 3])

   peak_start  peak_end  motif_start  motif_end strand
2          62       419      3223269    3223287      -
3          62       419      3223229    3223247      +
4          62       419      3223232    3223250      +
```

Answer (score 3):

Use  [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
m = df.groupby(['peak start'])['peak start'].transform('size')
#if you want to consider both
#m = df.groupby(['peak start', 'peak end'])['peak start'].transform('size')
```

now you can filter your dataframe:

```
df.loc[m.between(2, 8)] #inclusive = True by default 

    peak start  peak end    motif_start   motif_end    strand   
0   948         177         3210085       3210103      -        
1   948         177         3210047       3210065      +        
2   062         419         3223269       3223287      -        
3   062         419         3223229       3223247      +        
4   062         419         3223232       3223250      +
```

---

```
df.loc[m.eq(2)]

    peak start  peak end    motif_start   motif_end    strand   
0   948         177         3210085       3210103      -        
1   948         177         3210047       3210065      +
```

---

```
df.loc[m.eq(3)]


    peak start  peak end    motif_start   motif_end    strand
2   062         419         3223269       3223287      -        
3   062         419         3223229       3223247      +        
4   062         419         3223232       3223250      +
```

---

We can also use `value_counts`

```
m = df['peak start'].value_counts()
df.loc[df['peak start'].map(m).eq(2)]
```

or [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)

```
n = 2
my_range = range(2-1, 8+1)
df.groupby('peak_start').filter(lambda group: len(group) == n)
df.groupby('peak_start').filter(lambda group: len(group) in my_range)
```